# Angular 6 with Fusionchart - Module not found: Error: Can't resolve fusionmaps/maps/fusioncharts.world

Tags: angular, fusioncharts

I am going to create first interactive map using FusionChart (FC). From the documentation https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/getting-started/angular/angular/your-first-map-using-angular I done all the steps. However, during `ng serve` I noticed the error:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fusionmaps/maps/fusioncharts.world' in '/var/www/html/my-app/src/app'
>
> ./src/app/app.module.ts
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fusionmaps/maps/fusioncharts.world' in '/var/www/html/my-app/src/app'

From console, I see the additional errors like:

> GET http://localhost:5200/fusioncharts.world.js net::ERR_ABORTED
>
> Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:5200/fusioncharts.world.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

FusionChart version I'm using:
[image]

in my `app.module.ts`:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FusionChartsModule } from 'angular-fusioncharts';
import * as FusionCharts from 'fusioncharts';
import * as FusionMaps from 'fusioncharts/fusioncharts.maps';
import * as World from 'fusionmaps/maps/fusioncharts.world';

import * as FusionTheme from 'fusioncharts/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fusion';
// Pass the fusioncharts library and chart modules
FusionChartsModule.fcRoot(FusionCharts, FusionMaps, World, FusionTheme);

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    //NgxPayPalModule,
    //Angular4PaystackModule,
    FusionChartsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

In `app.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'my-app';
  public payPalConfig?: PayPalConfig;
  dataSource: Object;

  constructor() {
        this.dataSource = {
            "chart": {
                "caption": "Average Annual Population Growth",
                "subcaption": " 1955-2015",
                "numbersuffix": "%",
                "includevalueinlabels": "1",
                "labelsepchar": ": ",
                "entityFillHoverColor": "#FFF9C4",
                "theme": "fusion"
            },
            // Aesthetics; ranges synced with the slider
            "colorrange": {
                "minvalue": "0",
                "code": "#FFE0B2",
                "gradient": "1",
                "color": [{
                    "minvalue": "0.5",
                    "maxvalue": "1.0",
                    "color": "#FFD74D"
                }, {
                    "minvalue": "1.0",
                    "maxvalue": "2.0",
                    "color": "#FB8C00"
                }, {
                    "minvalue": "2.0",
                    "maxvalue": "3.0",
                    "color": "#E65100"
                }]
            },
            // Source data as JSON --> id represents countries of world.
            "data": [{
                "id": "NA",
                "value": ".82",
                "showLabel": "1"
            }, {
                "id": "SA",
                "value": "2.04",
                "showLabel": "1"
            }, {
                "id": "AS",
                "value": "1.78",
                "showLabel": "1"
            }, {
                "id": "EU",
                "value": ".40",
                "showLabel": "1"
            }, {
                "id": "AF",
                "value": "2.58",
                "showLabel": "1"
            }, {
                "id": "AU",
                "value": "1.30",
                "showLabel": "1"
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

In `.html` file:

```
  <fusioncharts
    width="800"
    height="550"
    type="world"
    [dataSource]="dataSource">
</fusioncharts>
```

here is the content of package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.0",
    "angular-fusioncharts": "^3.0.0",
    "angular4-paystack": "^2.3.2",
    "core-js": "^2.6.2",
    "fusioncharts": "^3.13.3-sr.1",
    "ng2-password-strength-bar": "^1.2.3",
    "ngx-paypal": "^4.0.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.2.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.27"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.8.9",
    "@angular/cli": "^6.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.14",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.4.2",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~2.9.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: can i know, which version of angular fusioncharts you are using ?

Comment: @AshokMandal v3.13.3-sr.1

Comment: angular-fusioncharts version ?

Comment: can you share your code snippet too

Comment: @AshokMandal I have attached the image where you can see the version of FC I'm using.

Comment: @AshokMandal See the codes in my updated question.

Comment: code looks correct , can you see package.json file, and mention version of angular-fusioncharts then we can help you that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186704/discussion-between-niladri-banerjee-uttarpara-and-ashok-mandal).

Answer (score 1):

Ashok helped me as his best and he provided me the solution in my email (as we discussed in the chat). I have implemented what he gave me over email and it worked well. Now, I compared my code with the code he provided to me. I saw a little changes. See below:

**not working**

```
import * as World from 'fusionmaps/maps/fusioncharts.world';
```

**working:**

```
import * as World from 'fusioncharts/maps/fusioncharts.world';
```

I think, the documentation is wrong in fusioncharts site.